# Navigation menu not switching from hover to toggle based on the screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make my webpage switch buttons from on hover to on toggle when the width of the screen is less than 769px.
The hover or toggle script is selected based on what size the browser starts on and cannot switch when changing the size .

```js
$(document).ready(myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
  if (ww < 769) {
    $(".button").click(function() {
      $("ul").toggle();
    });
  } else {
    $(".button").hover(function() {
      $("ul").toggle();
    });
  }

}
```

```css
.button {
  display: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">Men</a>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Add document ready and resize events, both of them combined, to make when the document is ready and when the window is resized too.

I make an improvement with the events, take a look at the `on()` function

```js
$(document).ready(myFunction);
$(window).on('resize', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var event;
  var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
  if (ww < 769) {
     event = "click";
  } else {
     event = "hover";
  }


    // here is the improvement
    $(".button").on(event, function() {
      $("ul").toggle();
    });

}
```

```css
.button {
  display: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button">Men</a>
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`click` and `hover` are used to add event handlers not trigger events, to manually cause an event use `trigger()`.